# how would you base64 curl

Tags: bash, shell

sending an image to plantin , but it needs to be encoded in base64 to accept it...

```
#!/bin/bash


img="$(cat garage-cam.jpg | base64)"


set prompt "#"

send "curl 'https://myplantin.com/next-api/trpc/plant-problems.diagnose?batch=1' \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
  -H 'Authorization: 044c8b07-eafe-4df9-895c-993502c8957e' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Cookie: G_ENABLED_IDPS=google; pln-token=044c8b07-eafe-4df9-895c-993502c8957e; pln-user-premium=true; pln-user-id=13265880; amp_d5c551=0dmtVtWfuoKAICgbsaX_1K.MTMyNjU4ODA=..1gni9mah5.1gniat51t.37.4.3b' \
  -H 'Origin: https://myplantin.com' \
  -H 'Referer: https://myplantin.com/plant-problems' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS armv7l 13597.84.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.105 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="104"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Linux"' \
  --data-raw '("0":{\"json\":{\"images\":[{\"base64\":\"data:image/jpeg;base64, "image=@$img" }]}}) "' \
  --compressed

echo $res | grep -qo '"status":200' && link=$(echo $res | sed -e 's/.*"link":"\([^"]*\).*/\1/' -e 's/\\//g')
```

Comment: You are already base64 encoding your example image with `img="$(cat garage-cam.jpg | base64)"`. Therefore, this question needs some additional context. Can you verify that `img` is indeed the base64 encoding of your image? If so, then the issue is related to your HTTP request and not the base64 content.

Comment: What is the `send` command? You appear to have some quoting problems that are going to cause a variety of issues (e.g., you're trying to use variables inside of single quotes, where they won't be expanded). Also, I think your use of `@$img` inside your `--data-raw` argument isn't doing what you think it's doing. You would probably be better off constructing your JSON *before* calling curl, and then referencing the generated file (because then you can check the file for correctness).

Comment: There may also be some limits on command line length that you run into. I would put the image data into a file. Also worried about your quoting. You may need to escape some of those double quotes.

Comment: hor53 - sorry the title is what they allowed me to use.

Comment: main use is to take a jpg , turn it into base64 , send that all to myplantin.com , read website that follows..

Comment: The double quotes around the arguments to the `send` command are not closed.  Paste your code in https://www.shellcheck.net/, it will suggest syntax issues to fix.  Notice how the `echo` line is still syntax highlighted green.